# Windows Unicode keyboard hook

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, keyboard, hook

I'm developing an application that in some point needs to capture the keyboard and mouse user input. I had no problems installing and using the mouse hook, but the keyboard is not working properly.
I need to capture wide characters from multiple keyboard layouts.
I found something relevant but did not solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976108/keyboard-hook-not-capturing-unicode-in-other-threads

That's what I have without the not necessary stuff

WinMain:

```
//Set the hook, with threadId = 0
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, hInstance, 0); 
HKL keyboardLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
//All the window and message queue code
```

KeyboardProc:

```
WCHAR unicodeChar;
BYTE keyboardLayout[256];
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* keyParam = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;

if(code < 0)
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);

if(wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
{
    GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);

    int translation = ToUnicodeEx(keyParam->vkCode, keyParam->scanCode, keyboardState, &unicodeChar, 1, 0, keyboardLayout);
    translation = ToUnicodeEx(keyParam->vkCode, keyParam->scanCode, keyboardState, &unicodeChar, 1, 0, keyboardLayout);

    if(translation == 0 )//|| translation == -1)
        return 0;

    PushToBuffer(&unicodeChar);
}

//return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
return 0;
```

I left the commented code to show what I've already tried based on that post I mentioned and MSDN documentation.
The push to buffer receives a wchar_t pointer and stores it in a wstring used as a buffer, that dumps in a wofstream.

What happens:

If I call ToUnicodeEx once, the user input is modified and any dead-key is shown twice for him: for example, in a International English Layout, where you press ' then a to print an á, it shows: ''a. With the application closed the user input goes back to normal.

If I call ToUnicodeEx twice, the dead-key is consumed and I simply the char is shown.

I wonder why the user input is being modified, since I do not change any of the parameters given by the callback caller.
Is unicode not possible for low-level hooks?

Comment: You can't make this work with a low-level keyboard hook.  The callback runs in your process, not the process that is going to get the keystroke.  You retrieve the wrong keyboard state.  You can't get the keyboard state for the other process.

Answer (score -1):

ToUnicodeEx is broken when it comes to dead keys.  This is what your looking for: https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/source/browse/tags/1.1.4/src/native/windows/WinUnicodeHelper.c